# Launch activity in activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm trying to make Android application in Eclipse which should consist of 2 activities : first activity where user fills in fields and second activity which should be launched by pressing a button in first activity.

I've read many topics about intents, received all possible information about intent filters, but i still can't just create a button and use intent to launch activity.

Help, please.

It will be awesome if you've got something like a step-by-step instruction how to do that.

Ok, here's what i've made following your answers -->

I've created an application.
There are 4 java files in src :
Activity1.java - activity which i want to have a button to launch Activity2,

Activity2.java - which is in default state,
MyActivity.java - created to paste code received by 1Up,
View.java - empty class, which i created because without it i see many errors, dunno how to normally remove them.

Then i put 1Up's code in MyActivity, edited it slightly and this is what i've got :

```
public class Activity1<i> extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity1, menu);
    return true;
}
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    public void goToOtherActivity(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }                                        }
```

Then i thought now i can attach goToOtherActivity to onClick in Activity1 but it was able to be added only like text, so when i launch app on AVD it gives a lot of warnings

Comment: You should post what have you tried and not let us guess. Imagine someone else reads this question. How on Earth is he going to support you if you're providing only above?

Comment: My code was meant to go into Activity1. It crashes because it cannot find the method "goToOtherActivity" unless it is in the same activity of the button itself.

Comment: I've moved this code in Activity1 and i still can't attach goToOtherActivity to my button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go in following way to launch activity

```
Intent intent= new Intent(YourFirstActivity.this, YourSecondActivty.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

if you want some result back to First Activity

YOu shall start with

```
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

and implement onActivityResult

Do this 
set `onClick="onClick"` in you xml

like

```
<Button android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

#### Then in your java

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent intent= new Intent(YourFirstActivity.this, YourSecondActivty.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Learn more from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29)

Comment: button doesn't do any thing it fires onClick event and the method get called

Comment: ur xml we just suggested so simple thing just add onClick attribute to xml and create a method with public and view parameter post whole xml or button's xml

Comment: that's okay there is no problem in this method

Comment: I solved it - problem was in imported packages : i've just added android.view.View and everything started to work just like a wanted !

Thanks a lot, Indian Cyber Warrior

Comment: @lucifer63 You're welcome to import press ctrl + shift + O it will add all necessary import

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if you want to start new activity when some event is trigger (on click)

here is XML layout for example

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/start_btn"
        android:layout_width="75.0dip"
        android:layout_height="27.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="35.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/green_btn"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/start_image"
            android:layout_width="9.0dip"
            android:layout_height="14.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/start_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/start_caption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Start Activity"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

`Intent` can be is use to start new activity

```
LinearLayout lBtn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
lBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Intent mAct = new Intent(this, ActivtyClass.class);
     startActivity(mAct);
    } });
```

Comment: Where should i put this ?
And how to make a button use this intent ?

Answer (score 2):

You create your Intent to your new Activity, add any extras, and start the activity through a context:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyOtherActivity.class);   //Initialize the Intent
i.putExtra("firstExtra", value);         //Put any extra you want
i.putExtra("secondExtra", secondValue);  //Remember the key you used
context.startActivity(i);      //Start the activity with the given intent
```

You can put this inside your button's onClick event:

```
public void goToOtherActivity(View view)
{
    //CODE HERE
}
```

And define the button in xml like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btnGo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="goToOtherActivity"
    />
```

Then in the other Activity you can grab the extras and use them to do whatever you want:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Intent i = getIntent();   //Get the intent used to run this Activity
    Bundle b = i.getExtras(); //Get all the extras
    String firstExtra = b.getString("firstExtra"); //Get one String extra with key "firstExtra"
    int secondExtra = b.getInt("secondExtra"); //Get one Integer extra with key "secondExtra"
    //USE YOUR DATA
}
```

EDIT:

When I said put the code inside that method I meant to do something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        //onCreate code here
    }

    public void goToOtherActivity(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: as context use "this" if you are inside an Activity. So Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class) and this.startActivity(i)

Comment: this.startActivity(i); NOT this.startActivity2(i);

Comment: Edited question, please take a look